# Get GIFs/Video from my favorite Tweet and show it in a web page , via API

Tags: php, twitter, twitter-oauth

**My goal** : Show in a web page all the GIFs/Video present in my favorite tweet

To do this i'm using [Twitter REST APIs](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public) and [this php class (TwitterAPIExchange.php)](https://github.com/J7mbo/twitter-api-php/blob/master/TwitterAPIExchange.php)

Code for get my favorite tweet , this prints out the text of each of my favorite tweet

```
require_once('TwitterAPIExchange.php');


$settings = array(
    'oauth_access_token' => "XXXXXXX",
    'oauth_access_token_secret' => "XXXXXXX",
    'consumer_key' => "XXXXXXX",
    'consumer_secret' => "XXXXXXX"
);

$url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/favorites/list.json';
$getfield = '?count=200&screen_name=XXXXX&include_entities=false';

$requestMethod = 'GET';
$twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);

$result = $twitter->setGetfield($getfield)
             ->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
             ->performRequest();  

$result_array = json_decode($result , true);

for($i = 0 ; $i < count($result_array) ; $i++){
    echo $result_array[$i]["text"]."<br><br>";
}
```

Now I should extrapolate the http address of each GIFs/Video (and for that I have no problems) and view it, the problem is that the address of the GIFs/Video doesn't point directly to the GIFs/Video

### UPDATE 1

Now i tried this :

```
$url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/favorites/list.json';
$getfield = '?count=200&screen_name=XXXXX&include_entities=true';
.....
.....
$app_video = array();
for($i = 0 ; $i < count($result_array) ; $i++){
    array_push($app_video, $result_array[$i]["entities"]["urls"][0]["expanded_url"]);
}
```

to get an array with the links of all videos

### UPDATE 2

Now , after extrapolated the link of all videos (update 1), with **file_get_contents** and using **DomDocument** , i have extrapolate the

```
<video> <source ...> </ video>
```

from the page.

### UPDATE 3

This is my final solution

```
require_once('TwitterAPIExchange.php');


$settings = array(
    'oauth_access_token' => "XXXXXX",
    'oauth_access_token_secret' => "XXXXXX",
    'consumer_key' => "XXXXXX",
    'consumer_secret' => "XXXXXX"
);

$url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/favorites/list.json';
$getfield = '?count=200&screen_name=XXXXX&include_entities=true';

$requestMethod = 'GET';
$twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);

$result = $twitter->setGetfield($getfield)
             ->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
             ->performRequest();  

$result_array = json_decode($result , true);


for($i = 0 ; $i < count($result_array) ; $i++){

   $link = $result_array[$i]["entities"]["urls"][0]["expanded_url"];

   if(strpos($link,"twitter.com") !== false){

        $pageContent = file_get_contents($link , true);

        @$dom = new DOMDocument;
        @$dom->loadHTML($pageContent);

        $p = $dom->getElementsByTagName('video')->item(0);
        $source = $p->getElementsByTagName('source');

        $src = $source->item(0)->getAttribute("video-src");


        echo '<video name="media" loop="true" autoplay="true" src="'.$src.'">';
            echo '<source video-src="'.$src.'" type="video/mp4" class="source-mp4" src="'.$src.'">';
        echo '</video>';

   }

}


function get_inner_html( $node ) { 
    $innerHTML= ''; 
    $children = $node->childNodes; 
    foreach ($children as $child) { 
        $innerHTML .= $child->ownerDocument->saveXML( $child ); 
    } 
    return $innerHTML; 
}
```

---

### **This solution works, but i think i can do better. In this way , i have to load each page of each tweet , and of course this method is very slow.**

---

Answer (score 0):

do you ever heard about yahoo pipes? Thats a pretty cool, fast and easy way to spider website informations. After you have setup your pipes u can just read the rss/json that yahoo gives u. I know thats not a real answer due to you just outsource the information getter but in the end your code will be much faster and easier. I would write this as a comment but sadly stackoverflow doenst allow comments below 50 reputation.

https://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest not using the api, and instead use CURL to make a request against you fav list on twitter.  I would think that if you can to a curl request and get the page's html you can filter that down to the source and recreate it in your new page.

information on php and cURL: http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php
page to scrape with cUrl: https://twitter.com/favorites